# How to access all files in folder in google drive using url of one file

Tags: google-drive-api

I have url of one of the files in a folder in google drive.How can i get access to all the files/folders to all the files or that particular folder in google drive?

This is the link : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5ayIPzDlSdHVWRIV0tVMUlxdTg&usp=sharing_eid&ts=577165cb

I want access to the folder without owner's permission

Comment: What have you done so far?
Just want to confirm. Are you the owner of this drive account?

Comment: @noogui haven't done much,I am new to it ...I am not the owner of the drive account

Comment: looks like hacking to me. You have to be owner of the Drive account.

Comment: @noogui It was my account but now i can't access it ...neither are the recovery options working for me.....may be you can call it hacking but it actually isn't for me since i want my data only

Comment: This won't work unless you talk to the current owner of the Drive account. Even Service Accounts require certain permissions.

Comment: @noogui there is no current owner of the account

Comment: more than anything, I think this is a matter of account recovery.

Comment: Yeah but I am not able to recover ut